# using BehaviorSubject in a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have service which as the following code:

```
private caseListSource = new BehaviorSubject({});
caseList$ = this.caseListSource.asObservable();

loadCaseList() {
    return this._httpClient.get<Case>(environment.api_url +'/cases').do(data =>{
      this.caseListSource.next(data);

    });
```

In my components, I am doing the following:

```
caseList:any;

ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription = this._caseService.loadCaseList().subscribe(data => 
                                                                this.caseList = data);
  }
```

Currently, I am using `do` to call next on the `BehaviorSubject`.  Is there a better way to do this? Should I call `.next()` within m subscribe call instead?  Would I call `next` in every component that wants to be notified?

Initially I wasn't using a `BehaviorSubject`, but when I would login to my application and go to a `select` route, the `ngOnInit` in the select component would populate the caseList and I would use this in another component as well.  Once I refresh a page such as `case\2988`, the caseList would come back as undefined.

Comment: So you're using `BehaviorSubject` as a cache?

Comment: @martin - Probably, I updated my post of my initial problem.

Comment: Maybe you could save the stream (`this._httpClient.get...`) as a public property (or exposed through a function) and put the `shareReplay(1)` operator on the end. Then when someone subscribes for the first time it will invoke it and it will share the result with all future subscribers.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the use of BehiavorSubject instead of using shared variables in a service. If I create a service with shared variables and even overwrite them, the angular components also detect these changes, then why should I use BehiavorSubject instead of shared variables? for example, an array.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating 3 different Observables?

`private caseListSource = new BehaviorSubject({});` Is an Observable;

`caseList$ = this.caseListSource.asObservable();` Is an Observable;

`return this._httpClient.get<Case>(environment.api_url +'/cases')` is another Observable;

Just return the http call in `loadCaseList` and you will have the http call reponse observable. something like:

```
loadCaseList() {

  return this._httpClient.get<Case>(environment.api_url +'/cases');

}
```

If you want to maintain a copy of your Observable, you can assing the call to a private variable, like:

```
loadCaseList() {

  this.caseListSource = this._httpClient.get<Case>(environment.api_url +'/cases');

  return this.caseListSource;

}
```

UPDATE

Seems that you are using BehaviorSubject to provide the initial value for the Observable.

If it is true, you can use `SwitchMap` to swith between the `BehaviorSubject` instantiated on component initialization and the return of the HTTP call:

```
private caseListSource = new BehaviorSubject({}); // creates the behaviorSubject with an initial value

loadCaseList() {

  return this.caseListSource.switchMap(() => {

    return this._httpClient.get<Case>(environment.api_url +'/cases');

  });

}
```

This way you can have the initial value and than switch to the http call after `loadCaseList` being called.

Comment: I really did it this way because every example I see using BehaviorSubject does this.  I updated my post with why I started using one?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the `switchMap` usage.

Comment: caseListSource value isn't updated in your example, this defies the purpose of using it as cache.

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSubjects are useful if you want to make only one request, when your application is started.

If it is the case, then your component should subscribe to the subject :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription = this._caseService.caseList$
     .subscribe(data => this.caseList = data);
}
```

If you don't care about making several requests, then you should not use it.

(This is my opinion & way of doing things, I might be wrong, so don't take my word for the absolute and only truth)

Comment: I thought the point of BehaviorSubject was all components subscribed to it would be notified every time a request is made?

Comment: And so will subjects, but I'm explaning you how behavior subjects are used as cache when you do what you would like to do.